# Convert xml to JSON in java servlet

Tags: java, json, jdom

I have to call a perl script from a java servlet which returns an xml file. Then the java servlet converts the xml to json using jdom.
 So far, I've been successful in getting the xml. I tried a lot in vain to create the json using jdom. Any help will be appreciated.

The XML file looks somewhat like this.

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<results total="5">
<result cover="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg" title="aaaaa" year="dddd" director="qqqqqq" rating="yyy" details="666666"/>
</results>
</rsp>
```

There are 5 such result rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach documented at this [link](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/)

In summary, add **net.sf.json-lib** to your project.

Then use the `net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer` as shown in following code.

```
net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer(); 
JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xmlString );  
System.out.println( json.toString(2) );
```

There is a github project with the source code [here](https://github.com/tobrien/sample-json-parsing)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I did go through the first link (stackoverflow page). But as a spec of this project, I'm not allowed to use only JDOM for xml to json conversion.

Comment: If the xml always be in the structure shown in your question, then it may be easier to use regex to pull out the data you require and then use that data to build a simple string representing the json.

Comment: Yeah. But the part of specification is also to generate a json and perform some further operations on it.

Comment: what further operations?  you should add all the additional constraints to your question.